# Make ControlActive respond faster within Animate

Tags: manipulate, animation

The following code uses [Animate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Animate.html) to create an animation that displays as {t, "Inactive"} when paused, and {t, "Active"} when running:

```
Animate[ControlActive[{t, "Active"}, {t, "Inactive"}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Paused animator not yet refreshed]

However, [ControlActive](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ControlActive.html) is strangely slow to refresh when the animation is paused. Try it by evaluating the above and pressing the pause button. It takes around 1 second for {t, "Inactive"} to replace {t, "Active"}.

In constrast, ControlActive is very responsive within [Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html). Try moving the slider here after evaluating this:

```
Manipulate[ControlActive[{t, "Active"}, {t, "Inactive"}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

The difference seems to hinge on the [Animator](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Animator.html) control. For example ControlActive becomes slow again when using that control with Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[ControlActive[{t, "Active"}, {t, "Inactive"}], {t, 0, 10, Animator}]
```

Any ideas on why ControlActive refreshes more slowly within Animate or how to tweak it?

Comment: I've ran into this issue myself. I think it is a "refractory period" to give the user time to adjust things before processing the more time-consuming output. It's possible it has something to do with an UpdateInterval or something like that in the specific control being used. // One thing I just noticed: Play with the Animate version, immediately move the Manipulate version. They will *both* be slow to update and update at exactly the same time.

Comment: Interesting observations. I didn't have any luck playing with UpdateInterval.

Answer (score 8):

First, no, I don't have a sound reason why `ControlActive` is so slow inside `Animator`. I can only guess and this doesn't help anyone. Additionally, I don't have the slightest idea how to tweak it in a simple way. Here is what tried anyway:

I first thought of hacking a simple version of `ControlActive` myself which is three lines of code

```
DynamicModule[{i, $active}, {Slider[Dynamic[i, 
 {($active = True; i = #) &, Automatic,($active = False; i = #) &}]], 
 Dynamic[i], Dynamic[$active]}]
```

The idea is to introduce a variable which is set to `True` when you start changing a slider and reset to `False` when you are finished. This is the equivalent of [`$ControlActiveSetting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ControlActiveSetting.html) which is used by `ControlActive`.

This approach could be packed in a `MyControlActive` function and used inside dynamic code:

```
DynamicModule[
 {i, $active, MyControlActive},
 MyControlActive[a_, b_] := If[$active, a, b];
 Panel[
  Column[{
    Slider[
     Dynamic[i, {($active = True; i = #) &, 
       Automatic, ($active = False; i = #) &}], {1, 10}],
    Dynamic@
     Plot3D[Sin[i x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
      PlotStyle -> MyControlActive[None, Automatic], Mesh -> True, 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
    }]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The unexpected part is, that `Animator` is completely resistant to this approach.

```
DynamicModule[{i, $active},{Animator[Dynamic[i, 
 {($active = True; i = #) &, Automatic, ($active = False; i = #) &}]],
Dynamic[i], Dynamic[$active]}]
```

This shows always `False`. But why? The original idea assumes, that the 3 functions given to `Dynamic` are executed one after another. We made this assumption due to the [documentation of Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) where we find

> For interactive mouse operations `Dynamic[expr,{fstart,f,fend}]` typically evaluates  once `fstart` when the mouse is pressed, then evaluates  `f` whenever the mouse is moved, and then evaluates `fend` once when the mouse is released.

Lets build a small `DynamicModule` which keeps track of the `Clock` when moving a `Slider` or using `Animator`

```
DynamicModule[{t1, t2, t3, i},
 Panel[Column[{
    Dynamic[i],
    Dynamic[{t1, t2, t3}],
    Animator[
     Dynamic[i, {(t1 = Clock[]; i = #) &, (t2 = Clock[]; 
         i = #) &, (t3 = Clock[]; i = #) &}], 
     AnimationRunning -> False],
    Slider[
     Dynamic[i, {(t1 = Clock[]; i = #) &, (t2 = Clock[]; 
         i = #) &, (t3 = Clock[]; i = #) &}]]
    }]
  ]]
```

What we notice is that when we use the slider of `Animator` then `fstart`, `f` and `fend` are always executed. It doesn't matter whether I click or drag or stop dragging. Compare it to the behavior of the `Slider` at the bottom.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it seems we cannot use such a simple approach. Another thing which could work is to continuously check whether the variable inside `Animator` is changing. In the simplest way one would use `Refresh` and check whether the animator-time is equal to the last checked value. If yes, we are not active. If it is different, we are active. In either way we save the current value of the animator time:

```
DynamicModule[{t = 0, tt = 0, MyControlActive},
 MyControlActive[a_, b_] := 
  If[Refresh[If[t != tt, tt = t; True, tt = t; False], 
    UpdateInterval -> .1, TrackedSymbols :> {}], a, b];
 Panel[Column[{
    Dynamic[{NumberForm[t, {1, 3}], MyControlActive[True, False]}],
    Animator[Dynamic[t], AnimationRunning -> False]}]
  ]]
```

Works like a charm for this simple code and will, I'm sure, lead to difficulties in a real-life example :-) Here, we can set `UpdateInterval` to whatever value is needed but if it is too small, we get some `False` peaks during a running animation.

Comment: Thanks, great research into the problem, and a good suggested workaround at the end.