# Manipulate Iterated Logarithm

Tags: manipulate

Could I create a third slider that controls two other sliders?

I would like to master slider to move slider `k` from min to max, at which point, the master slider should be half way across.

Slider `j` should then "engage", and run from min to max, by which time, the master slider should be at max.

I should also like to hide sliders `k` and `j`, so that only the master slider is visible.

Is this possible?

```
r = 100; Manipulate[Plot[{If[k < E, Log[Log[x]/Log[k]], 0],
If[k == E,Log[Log[Log[x]/Log[j]]], 0], Log[x], Log[Log[x]], Log[Log[Log[x]]]}, 
{x, 1, r}, PlotRange -> {{0, r}, {0, Log[r]}}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Blue}, 
{Red, Dashing[0.005], Opacity[0.3]}, {Red, Dashing[0.005], Opacity[0.3]}, {Red, 
Dashing[0.005], Opacity[0.3]}}], {k, x^(1/x), E}, {j, x^(1/x), E}]
```

## Update

This is the closest I can get. Not perfect, but better ...

```
r = 100; j = x^(1/x); Manipulate[Plot[{If[k < E, Log[Log[k, x]], 
Log[Log[Log[k - E + x^(1/x),x]]]], Log[x], Log[Log[x]], Log[Log[Log[x]]]}, {x, 1, r},  
PlotRange -> {{0, r}, {0, Log[r]}}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Red, Dashing[0.005], 
Opacity[0.3]}, {Red, Dashing[0.005], Opacity[0.3]},{Red,Dashing[0.005], 
Opacity[0.3]}}], {k, x^(1/x), 2 E - 1}]
```

## Update 2

From Belisarius' great code below:

```
r1 = 1; r2 = 100; j = 3; 
Manipulate[Plot[{NestList[Log, Log[x]/Log[(1 - Mod[s, 1]) x^(1/x) + Mod[s, 1] E], 
Floor[s + 1]][[Floor[s + 1]]], NestList[Log, x, j]}, {x, r1, r2},
PlotRange -> {{r1, r2}, {0, Log[r2]}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True], {s, 0, j}]
```

Title changed to make it more fitting to question. Apologies to Martin John Hadley and bill s for misleading original title: **Create master slider in manipulate & hide others** *this was my first thought on how to approach this problem*. Thank you for your excellent responses, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
kk[s_] := (1 - Mod[s, 1]) #^(1/#) + Mod[s, 1] E &
r = 100;
Manipulate[
 Plot[{If[s < 1, Log[Log@x/Log@kk[s][x]], 
                 Log[Log[Log@x/Log@kk[s][x]]]], 
       Log@x, Log@Log@x, Log@Log@Log@x},
  {x, 1, r},
  PlotRange -> {{0, r}, {0, Log[r]}}],
 {s, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Perhaps simpler:

```
kk[s_, x_] := Log[Log@x/Log[(1 - Mod[s, 1]) x^(1/x) + Mod[s, 1] E]]
r = 100;
Manipulate[
           Plot[{If[s < 1, kk[s, x], Log@kk[s, x]], Log@x, Log@Log@x, Log@Log@Log@x}, 
                {x, 1, r}, PlotRange -> {{0, r}, {0, Log[r]}}], 
           {s, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Wonderful though ... couldn't have done this in a month of Sundays :)

Comment: Much clearer to add further functions to this - wish I could more than +1 :)

Comment: Thant looks deceptively simple! :)

Comment: ... Though much clearer to interpret mathematically since one function fits all :)

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you don't really want to have a slider for k and j at all, since you want to hide them. Accordingly, you can get the desired effect by creating variables j and k that take their values from the master slider:

```
mink = -10; maxk = 10; minj = 2; maxj = 12;
Manipulate[
 If[x < maxk, k = x; j = 0;, j = x - maxk; k = 0;]; {k, j}, {x, mink, maxk + maxj}]
```

I've arbitrarily chosen max and min values for the sliders and also arbitrarily set j to 0 when k is active and vice versa. Clearly you could change these to whatever you wish.

Comment: Min of both `j` & `k` are dynamic - they change with `x` - see code above.

Comment: @martin - one problem with your code is that `x` is localized within `Plot`, i.e. it would never reach the sliders.

Comment: It works for me ...

Comment: @martin - yes, but the the markers on the sliders don't move, so I never know where I am.

Comment: No - obviously working outside _Mathematica's_ comfort zone ;)

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to this game, but I want to suggest that you investigate `DynamicModule` for cases where you're interested in more control over the updating of dynamic content.

I built the following GUI that looks similar to what you described, notice that the k and j controller are greyed out as the master slider is less than 1/2 of it's maximum value:

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
DynamicModule[{master, k = 50, j = 50, range = {1, 100}}, 
Grid[{
{"Master", Slider[Dynamic[master], range],Dynamic[master]}, 
{Item[OpenerView[{"Advanced Controls", 
 Grid[{
 {"K Slider",Dynamic[If[master > range[[2]]/2, Slider[Dynamic[k],{1, 100}],Slider[k,{1,100}, Enabled -> False]]]}, 
 {"J Slider",Dynamic[If[master > range[[2]]/2, Slider[Dynamic[j],{1, 100}],Slider[j, {1, 100}, Enabled -> False]]]}}]}], 
 Alignment -> Left], SpanFromLeft}
}]]
```

**Update**

Here's the update where the master slider is updated by j and k. Note that dragging the master slider is meaningless.

```
DynamicModule[{k, j},
Column[{
{"Master", Dynamic@Slider[k + j, {0, 100}]},
{"K", Slider[Dynamic[k], {0, 50}]},
{"J", Dynamic@If[k < 25, Slider[0, {0, 50}], Slider[Dynamic@j, {0, 50}]]}}]
```

It would be possible to modify this so that the master slider could be updated directly, I think Halirutan has done some excellent work here that might be useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10976/1952.

Comment: Hmm. I think I may have misunderstood your question. I've added an update, but it may simply be irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: This is great - could the master slider be attached so there is 2-way control?

Answer (score 2):

```
r = 100;
Manipulate[

 Column[{

   Row[{"k", Spacer@5, Dynamic@Slider[Dynamic@k, {1.0001, E}]}],

   Row[{"j", Spacer@5, Dynamic@Slider[Dynamic@j, {1.0001, E}]}],

   Dynamic@
    Plot[{If[k < E, Log[Log[x]/Log[k]], 0], 
      If[k == E, Log[Log[Log[x]/Log[j]]], 0], Log[x], Log[Log[x]], 
      Log[Log[Log[x]]]}, {x, 1, r}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, r}, {0, Log[r]}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Blue}, {Red, Dashing[0.005], 
        Opacity[0.3]}, {Red, Dashing[0.005], Opacity[0.3]}, {Red, 
        Dashing[0.005], Opacity[0.3]}}, ImageSize -> 600]

   }],

 Deployed -> True,
 TrackedSymbols :> {k, j}
 ]
```

Comment: Can't get this to work for me I'm afraid

Comment: @martin - it works quite nicely with me (MM 9.01). The blue line goes through the dashed red lines. The last red line is touched when the k- and j-sliders are both in their rightmost position.

Comment: Min `k` & `j` should be `x^(1/x)`, not `1+ε`.